# Pass arguments into redirect_to(@post)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

From my Rails controller, in the `create` method I want to do

```
redirect_to @post(:notice => "Post successful', :status => "Success!")
```

and access the parameters in `show.html.erb` by using `<%= notice %>` and `<%= status %>`

But it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

`routes.rb` file:

```
Archive::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root :to => "Posts#new"
end
```

Comment: did my answer to the question below resolve your issue? If not, could you update me on what happened so I can help better answer your question.

Comment: Ah, I happened not to want do to this after I posted it. But your answer looks comprehensive. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's probably not working is that you are overriding the *HTTP Status Code* that is returned as part of the response. This status code, which is set by setting the `:status` in the redirect_to syntax, is used by the browser to determine it's particular action. You can read more about the different status codes here [W3C HTTP Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Long story short, in order for a successful redirect to occur, you need to have a `3XX` code for the browser to look at the location header in the HTTP response, and load the URL specified there. If you want the redirect to work properly, you can use the following syntax below.

```
redirect_to @post, :notice => "Post successful"
```

If for some reason you want to set it manually, you can do it like so:

```
redirect_to @post, :notice => "Post successful", :status => 301
```

There are also some symbols you can use in lieu of the numeric status codes, which you can read about in the [Rails documentation for redirect_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using:

```
redirect_to post_path , :notice => "Post successful", :status => "Success!"
```

Comment: do you have resources :posts in your routes?

Comment: can you paste your routes file?

Comment: In your old approach (the one you mentioned in your question) were you getting this routing error or was it hitting the show page but not displaying the flash message?

Comment: also you can do a rake routes ( from the root if your app ) to see what the path to the show action is supposed to be rendered as

Comment: post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}

Comment: looks good to me. does it give a same error when you do this redirect_to @post(:notice => "Post successful', :status => "Success!") per your question?

Comment: The old approach doesn't even allow displaying this `new` page. It says that the syntax `redirect_to @post(..` is wrong. But when I just do `redirect_to @post`, it's fine.

Comment: then do flash[:notice] =  "Post successful" ad use redirect_to @post and in the views use <%= flash.keep(:notice) %> since we are redirecting to the view